# How to check if at least a number in a string is different than 0?

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm trying to validate a number, which can only consist of numbers from 0 to 3,and at least one of the numbers must be different from 0. I just can't figure out how to effectively check if at least one number is !=0. Here is what i've come up so far.

Is there something i'm missing?

Thank you!

```
 public static boolean valid (String a, String b ){
      boolean valid =false;
      char min='0';
      char max='3';
       int c=0;

         if(a!=null&&b!=null){
              while(b.charAt(c)>=min&&b.charAt(c)<=max&&c<b.length()){
              valid=true;
               c++;
             if(b.charAt(c)<=min){
             valid=false;
       }
     }
} 
return valid;
```

}

Comment: what do 'a', 'b' parameter mean?

Comment: What's the purpose of `String a`? You don't seem to be using it at all.

Comment: String b, is the number i'm trying to validate. String a is another string that I need to validate, but it is not part of the problem I have(both string a and b need to be of the same length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing if at least one digit is not equal to zero (Assuming, in this case, that str represents a number)

```
public static boolean valid (String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() == b.length())
        for (char c : b.toCharArray())
            if (c != '0' && (c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3'))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```